# Infinitesimals of same variable

Tags: calculus

Let $y, x$ be variables defined by $y=x^2$. Then the differential element of $y$ which is $dy$ will be $2xdx$ meaning an infinitesimal increment in $x$ will change $y$ infinitesimally by $2xdx$. But here a change in $y$ is dependent on $x$. I mean $2x_1dx$ and $2x_2dx$ are not equal. Then why are they all the same infinitesimal $dy$? Does that mean infinitesimals of same variables are equal?

Comment: You can think of $dy$ as a function of $x$ and $dx$ if you like, one that takes a starting point and an infinitesimal displacement in $x$ and gives the infinitesimal displacement in $y$.

Comment: Any explanation on this topic?

Comment: The point is that there are different $dy$'s for different starting points $x$ and different displacements $dx$. In standard analysis there isn't really any further elaboration than that to be done because you aren't really using infinitesimals in the theory at all.

Comment: (Cont.)  In nonstandard analysis there's a bit more to be said, but the situation depends on the nonstandard analysis framework you use. In hyperreal analysis, $f(x+dx)-f(x)=f'(x) dx$ is not literally true, it is only true that $\frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)-f'(x) dx}{dx}$ is infinitesimal. In smooth infinitesimal analysis, $f(x+dx)=f'(x) dx$ is literally true if $dx$ is a nilsquare infinitesimal.

Comment: If I plug two different $x$-values into $y = x^3$, I get two different $y$-values. They're both still governed by the relationship $y = x^3$, even if they're different numbers. Same thing is true here if you plug two different $x$-values into $dy = 2xdx$. You'll get two different values for $dy$, but they'll both still be governed by the relationship $dy = 2xdx$.